# Max heap and Min heap implementation for median Java

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I have to create an ADT to read a number of data and calculate the median of those data. The ADT consist in a MIN and a MAX heap.
The `MinHeap` class takes the numbers greaters or equal than the median.

`public class MinHeap {`

```
public double[] data;
public int Size;

public MinHeap(int size) {
      data = new double[size];
      Size = 0;
}

public double getMinimum(){
    return this.data[0];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
      return (Size == 0);
}

private int getParentIndex(int nodeIndex) {
    return (nodeIndex - 1) / 2;
}

public void insertu(double value) throws Exception {
    if (Size == data.length)
          throw new Exception("Heap's underlying storage is overflow");
    else {
          Size++;
          data[Size - 1] = value;
          siftUp(Size - 1);
    }
} 
public void siftUp(int nodeIndex) {
    int parentIndex; 
    double tmp;
    if (nodeIndex != 0) {
          parentIndex = getParentIndex(nodeIndex);
          if (data[parentIndex] > data[nodeIndex]) {
                tmp = data[parentIndex];
                data[parentIndex] = data[nodeIndex];
                data[nodeIndex] = tmp;
                siftUp(parentIndex);
          }
    }
}
```

}`

The `MaxHeap`class takes the numbers that are less or equal than the median.

`public class MaxHeap{`

```
public double [] _Heap;
public int _size;
public int tam=0;

public MaxHeap (int a){

    _Heap = new double[a];
    _size = _Heap.length;
    for (int i = _Heap.length / 2 ; i >=0 ; i--) {
        tam++;
        maxHeapify(i); 
    }
}

private int parent(int pos) 
{ return pos / 2; }

private int leftChild(int pos)
{ return (2 * pos); }

private int rightChild(int pos)
{ return (2 * pos) + 1; }

private void swap(int fpos,int spos) {
    double tmp;
    tmp = _Heap[fpos];
    _Heap[fpos] = _Heap[spos];
    _Heap[spos] = tmp; 
}

private void maxHeapify (int i) {
    int l = leftChild(i), r = rightChild(i), largest;
    if(l < _size && _Heap[l] > _Heap[i]) {
        tam+=2;
        largest = l; 
        }
        else largest = i;
    if(r < _size && _Heap[r] > _Heap[largest]) {
        largest = r;
        tam+=2; }
    if (largest != i) {
        tam++;
        swap(i, largest);
        maxHeapify (largest); }
    } 

protected boolean isEmpty() { return _size == 0; }

protected void deleteMax() {
    if (_size > 1) {
        tam++;
        maxHeapify(0);
        double max = _Heap[0];
        _size--;
        swap(0, _size);
        maxHeapify(0); }
    else _size = 0;    
}

protected double extractMax() {
    maxHeapify(0);
    return _Heap[0];
}
public void insert(double element)
{
    _Heap[++tam] = element;
    int current = tam;

    while(_Heap[current] > _Heap[parent(current)])
    {
        swap(current,parent(current));
        current = parent(current);
    }   
}
```

}`

And the ADT:

```
`import java.util.InputMismatchException;`
`import java.util.Scanner;`
```

`public class ColaPrioridadMediana {`

```
private MinHeap MIN;
private MaxHeap MAX;
private int size;

public ColaPrioridadMediana(int cap) {
    if (cap%2==0){
        MIN = new MinHeap(cap/2);
        MAX = new MaxHeap(cap/2);
    }
    else{
        MIN = new MinHeap((cap+1)/2);
        MAX = new MaxHeap((cap+1)/2);
        }
    size = MAX.counter + MIN.Size;
}

public void insertar(double x) throws Exception{
    if (x <= MAX.extractMax()){
        if (MAX.counter > MIN.Size){
            double d = MAX.extractMax();
            MIN.insertu(d);
            MAX.insert(x);
        }
        else{
            MAX.insert(x);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (MIN.Size > MAX.counter){
            double d = MIN.getMinimum();
            MAX.insert(d);
            MIN.data[0] = x;
            MIN.siftUp(1);
        }
        else{
            MIN.insertu(x);
        }
    }
}

public int getSize(){
    return size;
}

public double getMediana() throws Exception{
    if(MAX.counter==MIN.Size){return ((MAX.extractMax()+MIN.getMinimum())/2);}
    else{
        if (MAX.counter<MIN.Size){return MIN.getMinimum();}
        else{return MAX.extractMax();}
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, Exception{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner num=new Scanner(System.in);
    ColaPrioridadMediana allNumbers=new ColaPrioridadMediana(10);
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Number:");
        try{
            String number=num.nextLine();
            double d;
            if(!number.isEmpty()){
                allNumbers.insertar(Double.parseDouble(number));
            }else{
                 d = allNumbers.getMediana();

            System.out.println("The result is " + d);
            System.out.println(allNumbers.MAX.extractMax());
            System.out.println(allNumbers.MIN.getMinimum());
            System.out.println(allNumbers.MAX.counter);
            System.out.println(allNumbers.MIN.Size);
            for (int i=0;i<allNumbers.MAX._Heap.length;i++){
            System.out.println(allNumbers.MAX._Heap[i]);
            System.out.println(allNumbers.MIN.data[i]);
            }

            System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Not number");
            }
        }
    }
```

}`

The MinHeap works, but the MaxHeap don't store any numbers, and prints only 0.0. I'm really stuck in here.

Answer (score 0):

In java, using the Java Standard class PriorityQueue to simulate Max-Min heap is not a bad idea. It will reduce coding significantly.

```
public class MaxMinHeap{
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((x,y)->(y-x));

private void add(int val) {
    if (maxHeap.size() == 0) {
        maxHeap.add(val);
    } else {
        int maxTop = maxHeap.peek();
        if (val <= maxTop) {
            maxHeap.add(val);
        } else {
            minHeap.add(val);
        }
        if (maxHeap.size() - minHeap.size() > 1) {
            minHeap.add(maxHeap.poll());
        } else if (minHeap.size() - maxHeap.size() > 1) {
            maxHeap.add(minHeap.poll());
        }
    }
}

private double findMedian() {
    if(maxHeap.size() > minHeap.size()) {
        return maxHeap.peek();
    }else if(maxHeap.size() == minHeap.size()) {
        return ((double) maxHeap.peek() + minHeap.peek()) / 2;
    }else {
        return minHeap.peek();
    }
}
```

}